# BIRT emitter, how to attach ids to the html columns

Tags: java, jquery, birt

I want to be able to set unique IDs to columns in the BIRT Report Designer and have these IDs propagated to the HTML table generated by my BIRT html emitter, this is so I can access the elements via its ID using jQuery. I looked around and haven't found an answer to this.

Here is a part of my BIRT html emitter:

```
public void startCell(ICellContent cell) throws BirtException {
    int colSpan = cell.getColSpan();
    int rowSpan = cell.getRowSpan();
    writer.write(inHeader ? "<th" : "<td");
    if(colSpan > 1){
        writer.write(" colspan=\""+colSpan+"\"");
    }
    if(rowSpan > 1){
        writer.write(" rowspan=\""+rowSpan+"\"");
    }
    if(cell.getStyleClass() != null && !cell.getStyleClass().isEmpty()){
        writer.write(" class=\""+cell.getStyleClass()+"\"");
    }
    writer.write(">");
}
```

I tried adding something like this:

```
if(cell.getName() != null && !cell.getName().isEmpty()){
     writer.write(" id=\""+cell.getName()+"\"");
}
```

That unfortunately doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create bookmarks in your report? - From a BIRT perspective that would be much cleaner (and easier) than writing your own emitter; bookmarks are implemented in all default emitters that come with BIRT.

The default HTML emitter uses the id-attribute for bookmarks.

Comment: As far as I can tell, columns don't support bookmarks. My project already has a custom html emitter for other reasons and I won't use the default birt emitter.

I'm still looking for a way to do this.